# How to position a figure in the itemize environment?

Tags: floats, itemize

I am trying to position my figure in the middle of the itemize environment. However, the left figure is always a little bit out of the left boundary. I marked the left boundary with a red horizontal. Does anyone know, how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

```
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item fdgdg
\begin{figure}[ht!]
   \centering
   \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Pspectrum_1024_Abweichung.png}}
   \hfill
   \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Pspectrum_2048_Abweichung.png}}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:Vergleich_Pspectrum}
\end{figure}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The only purpose of `figure` is to specify that the content is not part of the main document flow and can be inserted elsewhere, so latex goes to some lengths to make it _not_ look like it is part of the list (removing the current list indent, current font,  etc) To have an image _in_ the list just use `\includegraphics` then it will be indented to fit the list text.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I want to have two figures next to each other. By just using the command \includegraphics it won't work.

Comment: no, but two `\includegraphics` would.  Includegraphics images are positioned like letters they go side by side by default. If you need a caption for a non floating figure you could use `\captionof{figure}{....}` from the caption or capt-of packages

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the *figure* on a separate line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]{\def\@captype{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item fdgdg

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \setcaptype{figure}
   \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Pspectrum_1024_Abweichung.png}}
   \hfill
   \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{Pspectrum_2048_Abweichung.png}}
   \caption{}
   \label{fig:Vergleich_Pspectrum}
\end{minipage}

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```